# Create An Event and push to MailChimp using MailChimp Net V3

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3

Here's an (php) example of creating an Event and pushing it to MailChimp.
Anybody knows how this can be accomplished using C# and MailChimp Net V3?

PHP-example:
https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/guides/track-outside-activity-events/#create-an-event

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way, though you'll need to create a new Logic class.

```
public class MemberEventResponse
{
}

public class MailChimpMemberEventLogic : BaseLogic
{
    public MailChimpMemberEventLogic( MailChimpOptions options )
        : base( options )
    {
    }

    public async Task<MemberEventResponse> CreateMemberEventAsync( string listId, string email, string eventName )
    {
        var baseUrl = $"/lists/{listId}/members/{Hash(email)}/events";
        using ( var client = CreateMailClient( baseUrl ) )
        {
            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync( "", new { name = eventName } ).ConfigureAwait( false );
            await response.EnsureSuccessMailChimpAsync().ConfigureAwait( false );

            var listActivityResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MemberEventResponse>().ConfigureAwait( false );
            return listActivityResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just need to instantiate it, and create the event.

```
var logic = new MailChimpMemberEventLogic( _mailChimpOptions );
await logic.CreateMemberEventAsync( _mailChimpListId, email, eventName );
```

NB, I haven't looked into the response contents...